# NFS won't mount on boot

Tags: mount, nfs, nas

I am having trouble getting my nfs to mount on boot.  I am running Lubuntu 12.04 and mounting from a NAS (Synology-if it matters).  I should add that am very new to using Lubuntu or any Linux distribution.

To mount on boot I tried to add the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
192.168.2.15:/volume1/Family /home/john/nfs-Family nfs rw,async,hard 0 0
```

No luck when the computer mounts, the nfs file doesn't mount.

I should add that when I use the mount command the nfs mounts just fine. This is the command I use:

```
sudo mount 192.168.2.150:/volume1/Family /home/john/nfs-Family
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `auto` the list of options (rw,asy...), that should do it

Comment: have you tried checking to see if you client nfs daemon is running chkconfig netfs --list?

Answer (score 6):

This question is a bit old but I thought I might share what solved this problem for me. I had this same issue after following the [12.04 server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html).

Everything has worked well since I changed my `/etc/fstab` entry options to include **nfsvers=3** per comment #6 in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/891825). My current `fstab` entry (working on three clients) is as below.

```
192.168.1.0:/backup /home nfs nfsvers=3,hard,intr,auto 0 0
```

Comment: I've tried so many combinations and nothing worked. I just tried what you suggested and it finally works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It might be because the IP address of the NFS server in your fstab file is different from the one you use via CLI...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a few servers since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04. *nfsvers=3* didn't resolve the issue for me. Adding

```
mount -a
```

to `/etc/rc.local` did though.

Comment: didn't help here neither.

Comment: What helped, was using the IP address instead of the hostname in fstab. a `cat /var/log/syslog|grep nfs` told me: `mount[868]: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server kerberos: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Comment: or,  as alternative, put the hostname in the `/etc/hosts` file, so it is found easily before DNS resolution is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem using `x-systemd.automount`. So my line in `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

`10.4.111.123:/var/disk/auto_backup/backup       /var/disk/auto_backup/backup    nfs     _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=600,timeo=14 0 0`

*(ofcourse there are some TABs instead of spaces in it in some places)*

**Note:**

With this parameters nfs mount point will not appear in the response from `mount` automatically after OS starts. It will appear in the response from `mount` only after first access attempt (e.g. when some service/application will try to open that path or when user themself opened mounted folder in some file manager)