# NFS will mount but is not accessible until browsed through GUI

Tags: virtualbox, fstab, nfs

I'm using Windows 7 x64 as my normal OS, and using Ubuntu under VirtualBox.

I have haneWIN installed as NFS server, and I put the following under Ubuntu's /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.1.2:/websites /home/user/ror nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,udp,nolock,rw,user
```

The mount shows up as a folder in the task bar on bootup. However if I were to go straight into the console and type `cd ~/ror`, I get a `No such file or directory` error. So then I have to literally click on the folder icon on the task bar which opens the mount just fine. Then I go back into the console and type the same thing...it works. I can also type `mount -a` in the console and then it works. Why won't it do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/215752/248266

Solved my issue. Seems like a lame workaround that shouldn't be necessary but there it is.

All I needed to do was adding

```
mount -a
```

to `/etc/rc.local` file.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get the error `No such file or directory` is peculiar because:

In order for a drive to mount at `/home/user/ror` the directory must exist.

So even if the drive wasn't mounted you should be able to `cd` into the empty directory.

Do whatever it takes to reproduce the problem (probably reboot the VM).

And try the following:

Run `df -h` to see if the drive is mounted.

Try using a full path to the directory `cd /home/user/ror`

Or since the shell drops you into your home directory right away just: `cd ror`

Comment: Ah, you got me. I actually originally tried cd ~/ror/dev.manager (which is a subfolder in the NFS mount) and that's what wasn't working. I can actually cd into ~/ror (empty dir). But then the question is "why isn't it being mounted when there's nothing wrong with the script?"

Comment: That makes more sense. Just for troubleshooting, try removing all your extra paramters in fstab so replace `rsize...` with `defaults 0 0`

Comment: No joy. Same outcome.

Comment: Not sure if it's what should be expected from the average Ubuntu user, but following this advice, it works now: http://askubuntu.com/a/215752/248266